# How to compute Commutation matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

Commutation matrix is defined in:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix

assume I have matrix

```
A = [1,2,3;4,5,6];
```

How to get the Commutation matrix in MATLAB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it is "cheating", but you can try:

```
[m, n] = size(A);
I = reshape(1:m*n, [m, n]); % initialize a matrix of indices of size(A)
I = I'; % Transpose it
I = I(:); % vectorize the required indices
Y = eye(m*n); % Initialize an identity matrix
Y = Y(I,:); % Re-arrange the rows of the identity matrix
```

And the commutation matrix is then Y.

Comment: cool answer. Is it possible to reduce the memory by avoid the `eye(m*n)` since it may cause memory issue.

Comment: use speye. BTW, the commutation matrix is Y' not Y